# Restrict unauthenticated access to files with mod_rewrite and scripting language

Tags: apache, authentication, mod-rewrite, file-access

I have scavenged for the answers online but none seem to be similar to what I am trying to achieve. As such, I hope that gurus at stackoverflow can help me out.

**What is it that I am trying to accomplish?**
I want to restrict access to content for non-authorized users. Accessible content to non-authorized users will be specified in a white list. All other content is blacklisted.

**What is my environment?**
I am running Apache in conjunction with a scripting language very similar to that of PHP. The scripting language will not be known by many but it is Fazzt ( in case you do know and are able to infer the differences of it as compared to PHP... there are no pointers / memory management, decimal values, and binary data ). I have to use this environment due to the nature of the project.

**What is happening on the site?**
The site authenticates users and stores authentication in sessions. An unauthenticated user is presented with a styled ( contains images, css, js, etc ) webpage. Hence, I need to white-list all of the static images, css, js files in order for them to be available for download by the client browser. Once signed in, broader range of dynamic content is presented ( as such, anything that is not white-listed is automatically black-listed ).

**How did I plan to solve the problem?**
This is silly but I guess obvious is not always seen. My approach involved mod_rewriting all requests to existing files that do not match .fzt and .fsp pages. The rewrite would go to a scripting file that would check the requested file against the white list. If the file is present in the list, request would get routed directly to the file ( yes, silly me... it would get mod_rewritten again >_< ). If it's not in the list, user's authentication would be checked. If the user is not authenticated, "File not found" HTTP would be returned. Otherwise, the request would be redirected to the file and served ( same folly ).

As you can see, the approach is greatly flawed. However, I am sure something of the nature should be possible... yet, I have not found any proof just yet. What do you think? Is the mod_rewrite / script a completely wrong way of performing this task? How would you do it otherwise? Note that I cannot simply slap .htaccess as the access determined by user authentication that is tracked by Fazzt ( read above, scripting language similar to that of PHP ).

Any suggestions or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!